# Silverlight not loading inside WebBrowser control

Tags: winforms, silverlight, browser, embed

There is a web page with a silverlight control, when we use browsers like IE, chrome etc, they are all working.

We develop a desktop program, embed a WebBrowser control to a win form, and navigate to the web page, the silverlight object is not initializing, only shows the silverlight logo, just like the silverlight has not yet installed, but actuall it has installed and working.

Is it the limitation for silverlight or there should be some kind of security settings in IE or the WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run silverlight in browsers as well as in a 'client' application (WPF, using a webbrowser type control).  I can tell you in my project works without any issues, I've not had to change any settings apart from one - as I run it local host, IE prompts me about running in intranet mode.

You should use fiddler to see the exact URL that is being used in the navigation and to see if there are any errors returning from the web server.

I know it's not exact help, but I can confirm it should work.  Hopefully that can help narrow your search a little.